# Oracle sum from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to sum values from different tables as follows in an Oracle DataBAse from the PL/SQL Developer, so I prepared this SQL statement:

```
select sum(total) as ttt from
(select count('1') as total 
from vehicle_hotel 
union
select count('1') as total 
from alarm
union
select count('1') as total
from vd_poi
union
select count('1') as total
from person_hotel
union
select count('1') as total
from social_office_transaction
union
select count('1') as total
from person_hotel_field_value
union
select count('1') as total
from pd_trf_week
union
select count('1') as total
from aggreg_exception
union
select count('1') as total
from pd_week_rec;
select count('1') as total 
from hist_pd_week_rec
union
select count('1') as total
from pd_week);
```

But I got this error:

```
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 32, columna: 12
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` not `UNION` - if the count is the same in two tables then `UNION` will remove the duplicates and cause an under-count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has a handful of problems, which I fixed, listed below in descending order of bad to less bad:

- you had a stray semicolon inside the subquery `from pd_week_rec;` ... this is likely the cause of the particular error you were seeing
- you were using `UNION` between the subqueries, which could result in  incorrect results if two subqueries just happened to have the same count by coincidence
- you might want to assign an alias to your derived table (required by certain versions of SQL)
- you were using `COUNT('1')`, perhaps not wrong but I would use `COUNT(*)` instead

```
select sum(total) as ttt
from
(
    select count(*) as total 
    from vehicle_hotel 
    union all
    select count(*)
    from alarm
    union all
    select count(*)
    from vd_poi
    union all
    select count(*)
    from person_hotel
    union all
    select count(*)
    from social_office_transaction
    union all
    select count(*)
    from person_hotel_field_value
    union all
    select count(*)
    from pd_trf_week
    union all
    select count(*)
    from aggreg_exception
    union all
    select count(*)
    from pd_week_rec
    select count(*)
    from hist_pd_week_rec
    union all
    select count(*)
    from pd_week
) t;
```

Comment: Oracle does not require an alias for subqueries.  The problem is a semi-colon.  You should also explain why `union all` is correct and `union` won't necessarily return the correct results.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.  `select * from 
(select 1 record
from dual)` actually returns a record.  Until today I would have expected it to crash.

Comment: @DanBracuk Neither was I \:~(

Comment: [`COUNT(any_literal)` and `COUNT(*)` are identical.](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:1337911574066::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245)

Comment: @MT0 I said perhaps not wrong, but I have never seen `COUNT('1')` in a production codebase.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT('1')` and `COUNT(DATE '1970-01-01')` and `COUNT(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC')` and `COUNT(*)` all have identical functionality - `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are commonly used (mainly because they are the shortest to type) but that does not make using any of the other literals "wrong" and neither does the fact that it is uncommon and you have not seen it.

Comment: @MT0 `SELECT COUNT('Nothing strange here') FROM yourTable` ... would you honestly push this into your code base?

Comment: Not some meaningless string but if a literal has more semantic meaning than `1` or `*` then it could pass review.

Comment: @MT0 I agree with that.  I was arguing with you more from a code style point of view :-)  ... hopefully I know how `COUNT` works at this point.